# How does highlights view work in Chat?

Tags: support, chat, chat-highlights

[image: A picture of the bar at the top with highlights]

There's an option to view "highlights" in rooms on Chat. This hides some messages, but shows most of them. How are these determined? It seems to be random, other than showing all starred messages that would have loaded without highlights on.

Comment: @Glorfindel see the screenshot. It's in the bar at the very end of what has loaded in Chat.

Comment: @Glorfindel appears to be a new feature, coming out of the blue. And like many new features, it start with bugs.

Comment: Not new; Marc added this mode back in the summer of 2010, before chat's official release... For some reason, no one ever talks about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When in doubt, hover! :)

> [image]

In text:

> Only show starred messages, and messages to the current user

So, to make it clear, this **should** show the following messages:

- Starred messages
- Messages directed at you

**However**, testing it now, it appears to show other messages to, i.e. either it has a bug, or they pushed out the feature by mistake while it's not yet ready.

Comment: It seems to also show some feeds messages, but not all of them.

Comment: @NoDistractionWizard huh, good point. If you crack the formula, feel free to write a new answer. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Based on quick observation/experiment, looks like it shows **the most recent messages that are starred/directed at you**. The logic is more-or-less:

- Find the most recent messages that are starred/directed at you
- Show 5 messages before & after them to give context (some messages may overlap when there are consecutive starred messages/replies)
- Show up to N (around 90-100?) past messages in total.

---

Also, when "highlight" mode is enabled, **the user can still post a new message, and only their messages and replies at them are shown afterward.**

> [image: new messages when "highlight" mode is enabled]
>
> <sup>Observed from "highlight" mode</sup>
>
> [image: the actual conversation]
>
> <sup>Observed from incognito & no "highlight" mode</sup>

---

Lastly, **starred messages are cached the moment the user enters the "highlight" mode**. New starred messages won't be shown on the star wall (possibly a bug).

> [image: no new starred messages on the star wall when "highlight" mode is enabled]
>
> <sup>Observed from "highlight" mode</sup>
>
> [image: the actual star wall]
>
> <sup>Observed from incognito & no "highlight" mode</sup>

Comment: Sounds like SO unique homepage view, trying to show what you find interesting.